# Memory usage problem with powershell script

Tags: 2010, powershell, script

I recently had to build a powershell script to run trough all webs, subwebs, lists and items within a site collection to check what hasn't been used for a certain period.

This went ok in my development server, where I have a lot less items than in production.

When I attempted to run the script in the UAT server I ran in to a problem. I have some lists that are too big to be stored in the memory(1 million + items). This is happening because I use SPList.Items to get the list and then use a foreach to run trough all items of the list. But when I call SPList.Items powershell tries to store the entire list in the memory, which is impossible.

Is there a way around this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
# creates an object from the site collection url
    $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteUrl 

        # loop trough all webs in the site collection
        foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
        { 
            # loop trough all lists within the web
            foreach ($list in $web.Lists) 
            { 
                # remove hidden lists, master page/list template/theme/web part galleries and style libraries
                if( $list.Hidden -eq $false -and $list.Title -ne "Style Library" -and $list.Title -ne "Master Page Gallery" -and $list.Title -ne "List Template Gallery" -and $list.Title -ne "Theme Gallery" -and $list.Title -ne "Web Part Gallery")
                {                       
                    # loop trough all items within the list
                    foreach ($item in $list.Items) 
                    { 
                        # gets the date the item was last modified and calculates the difference to today
                        $modified = $item["Modified"]
                        $TimeSpan = [DateTime]$today - [DateTime]$modified
                        $age = $TimeSpan.days
                        $age=[math]::Round(($age/365),2)

                    # collects item info and stores in an object
                        $data = 
                        @{ 
                            "Type" = "Item"
                            "Site" = $site.Url 
                            "Web" = $web.Url 
                            "List" = $list.Title 
                            "ID" = $item.ID 
                            "URL" = $item.Url 
                            "Title" = $item.Title 
                            "Created" = $item["Created"] 
                            "Last Modified" = $item["Modified"]
                            "Time without update" = $age
                        }    
                        New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "Type", "Site", "Web", "List", "ID", "URL", "Title", "Created", "Last Modified", "Time without update"
                    } 
                    # gets the date the list was last modified and calculates the difference to today   
                    $modified = $list.LastItemModifiedDate
                    $TimeSpan = [DateTime]$today - [DateTime]$modified
                    $age = $TimeSpan.days
                    $age=[math]::Round(($age/365),2)

                    # collects list info and stores in an object
                    $dataList = 
                    @{ 
                        "Type" = "List"
                        "Site" = $site.Url 
                        "Web" = $web.Url 
                        "List" = $list.Title 
                        "ID" = $list.ID 
                        "URL" = "n/a" 
                        "Title" = $list.Title 
                        "Created" = $list.Created 
                        "Last Modified" = $list.LastItemModifiedDate
                        "Time without update" = $age
                    } 
                    New-Object PSObject -Property $dataList | Select "Type", "Site", "Web", "List", "ID", "URL", "Title", "Created", "Last Modified", "Time without update"
                }
            } 
            # gets the date the web was last modified and calculates the difference to today    
            $modified = $web.LastItemModifiedDate
            $TimeSpan = [DateTime]$today - [DateTime]$modified
            $age = $TimeSpan.days
            $age=[math]::Round(($age/365),2)

            # collects list info and stores in an object            
            $dataWeb = 
            @{
                "Type" = "Web"
                "Site" = $site.Url 
                "Web" = $web.Url 
                "List" = "n/a" 
                "ID" = $web.ID 
                "URL" = $web.Url 
                "Title" = $web.Title 
                "Created" = $web.Created 
                "Last Modified" = $web.LastItemModifiedDate
                "Time without update" = $age
            }
            New-Object PSObject -Property $dataWeb | Select "Type", "Site", "Web", "List", "ID", "URL", "Title", "Created", "Last Modified", "Time without update"
            $web.Dispose(); 
        } 
        $site.Dispose()
    }
```

I thought about using a CAML query to filter the results and then less items as the result, but I need all items and not just some so I can't really apply a filter to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a CAML query to get a subset of list items and page through the results.

Make sure you set the RowLimit on the query so that you only get a limited number of items at a time. You also need to include an OrderBy clause in your CAML query.

After retrieving the first page of results, set the your query's [SPQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.listitemcollectionposition.aspx) property to the same value as your ListItemCollection's `ListItemCollectionPosition` property and invoke `GetItems()` again to get the next page of results.

Example from [an MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2012/02/13/iterating-large-sharepoint-lists-with-powershell/):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://portal.sharepoint.com
$list = $web.Lists["LargeList"]

$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
$spQuery.RowLimit = 2000
$caml = '<OrderBy Override="TRUE"><FieldRef Name="ID"/></OrderBy>' 
$spQuery.Query = $caml 

do
{
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($spQuery)
    $spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    foreach($item in $listItems)
    {
        Write-Host $item.Title
    }
}
while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

### Miscellaneous Script Suggestions

**eliminate redundancy**

You don't need to pipe your psobjects created by the `new-object psobject` lines into the `select` cmdlet. `select` (actually an alias for `Select-Object`) simply creates a new psobject with the specified properties.

**further limiting the results**

Given your requirements, you may also want to add a Where clause to your CAML query so that you only retrieve items created or modified before/after a certain date. (Although if the Created/Modified fields aren't indexed, that may not work on large lists.) Additionally, each List object has a `LastItemModifiedDate` property that you can access, and maybe skip querying it depending on your scenario

**exporting to CSV**

If you want to export the data to Excel, PowerShell has a handy `Export-CSV` cmdlet that accepts an array of psobjects. Outside the loops, you can create an array using `$arr = @()`, then within the loop you can append your psobjects to it using `$arr += new-object psobject -property $data`. Finally, outside the loop, you can export the array to a CSV file using `$arr | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path "report.csv"`.

Comment: This looks great. I will try it tomorrow and update it here. Just one question, what is the $spQuery.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'" line?

Comment: That determines how the query treats folders. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39255908/2701677) for an explanation.

Comment: It worked like a charm. And it's way faster. In the dev server(where it ran because of the less amout of documents) its taking at least half the time. I am going to add the where clause, it's a good a idea!

Comment: Thanks @Thriggle. I have another question, if you don't mind. I was looking at my code and I noticed that I do this line    New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "Type", "Site", "Web", "List", "ID", "URL", "Title", "Created", "Last Modified", "Time without update" for each and every item in the loop. I thought this was wrong and moved this line to after the foreach(item in listitem) statement but now I have no results. I guess I don't really understood how this works. Would you mind clarifying? Thank you.

Comment: Within the loop, you're constantly overwriting the `$data` variable with a new hashtable of property values. If you want to see the value that's going into that variable, you could either append that variable to an array and access it later or write it directly to the output, but just trapping it in a variable does neither of those. Since the object created by `new-object psobject -property $data | select ...` is **not** being stored in a variable, it gets written directly to the PowerShell output.

Comment: I've folded some of my comments into the answer to keep the comments cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it. I will update my question with my updates later.